# How can I display the TextHint in a TCombobox when using style Ownerdraw

Tags: delphi

I am having to use ownerdraw with my Combobox but I still want to display the TextHint if the itemindex is -1.

I have placed this code in my ownerdraw event.

```
procedure TfmPPSMain.cmbFilesDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  if Index = -1 then  begin
    cmbFiles.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGray;
    cmbFiles.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, cmbFiles.Text);
  end
  else
  begin
    cmbFiles.Canvas.Pen.Color := clWindowTextHint;
    cmbFiles.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, cmbFiles.Items.Names[Index]);
  end;
end;
```

but the combobox remains persistently blank. Any suggestions would be helpful.h

Comment: (1) I assume the style is `csOwnerDrawFixed`. (2) I assume you either have name-value pairs in the list, or that you mean `cmbFiles.Items[Index]` instead of `cmbFiles.Items.Names[Index]`. (3) I suspect you mean `Canvas.Font.Color`, not `Canvas.Pen.Color`.

Comment: In any case, I suspect this is actually possible, but the VCL prevents it. Have a look at `Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomBomboBox.CNDrawItem`: Here you find `if Integer(itemID) >= 0 then DrawItem(...) else FillRect(...)` so that the event handler is only called if `itemID >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure you are right, I have put a watch on the OnDraw event and it doesn't get called. - how annoying, I suppose there is a reason for that?

Comment: I didn't quite get that. The event is fired, but never with `Index = -1` because of the code I mentioned: If `itemID` (=`Index`) is `-1`, then `DrawItem`, which calls the event, isn't called.

Comment: Sorry poorly worded.  The event doesn't get called when index is -1  otherwise it works as expected

Comment: Correct. And that is because `Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomBomboBox.CNDrawItem` gets called (both when index is -1 and <> -1), but if it is -1, then it doesn't call `DrawItem` which is the one calling the event handler. So the VCL blocks the -1 case.